# Meteor: TypeError: module.export is not a function

Tags: node.js, windows, meteor

Firstly installed [Node 6.10.3/Node 7.10.0](https://nodejs.org/en/)
Then installed [Meteor 1.4](https://www.meteor.com/)

I am trying to install Meteor in **Windows 8.1**, after installation it suggests to restart the computer. Did.

But now I'm getting an error saying

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, After looking at **Meteor's** changelog for **version 1.4.4** at, http://docs.meteor.com/changelog.html#v14420170407 , I guess you need to downgrade your **Node** and **npm** to **version 4.8.1 and 4.4.4** respectively.

You can grab your respective **Node** and **npm** versions here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Hope this helps!

Comment: downgraded to above mentioned versions, but still getting the same error.

Comment: I think you don't really want to install node and npm by yourself. After installing meteor in your PC then create a meteor app, the corresponding version of node (and npm with it) is installed with your meter app. So, installing node separately, before creating a meteor app, is not necessary.